# Fast 3D Lut lookups

Tags: c, graphics, colors, lookup

I'm trying to write a fast 3D lut lookup function and noticed that most luts are either 33x33x33 or 17x17x17.

Why 33 or 17? Wouldn't the math be quicker with 32 or 16 instead? So you could do some shifts instead of divides? Or maybe I'm not understanding why.

Anyone?

Comment: A **L**ook **U**p **T**able for what??

Comment: Sorry...a color lookup table used in color transformations. They usually hold RGB values in a float 0.0->1.0 format.

Comment: Floats are normally IEEE754 format. For C if `__STDC_IEC_559__` is defined - very likely, x86, ARM. For OpenGL it is, too. Are you sure this is Float and not some Fractinal format or integer?

Answer (score 3):

This paper will provide a synopsis: https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/98/HPL-98-95.pdf

Basically what you need is to divide the color space into a certain number of pieces and do linear interpolation between those pieces. It's a method of doing the lookup table such that you can find the color positions without much error but with a more sparced lookup than you would otherwise have.

And here's the reason: if you cut a line 2 times, you have 3 pieces.

The reason you have 17 or 33 rather than 16 or 32 is that you need the piece you are in, not the nearest position. If you divide you're going to bitshift a 2^8 value, you'll have 16 values that you could have. But, since you need to linear interpolation the position within that piece, you need 17 values.

In short, the reason you have 17 and not 16 is that with 17 you can evenly divide the value by 16 which is faster, and then check the value that occurs *after* your floored integer division, and then make an educated guess where you should be between those values. And that takes N+1 values in the lookup table.